# Smooth Operation In Image Processing

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to optimize my code,
My code contains following steps

```
//img size 1024 X 720
cvSmooth(img, inputImg, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 0, 0);
FilterOperations::sobelSchaar(inputImg, sobImg);
cvResize(sobImg, sob2Img);
//sob2Img size 512 X 360
cvSmooth(sob2Img, sob2Img, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 3);
imgProceObj.normalise(sob2Img);
cvAdaptiveThreshold(sob2Img, sob2Img, 255,
           CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 31, 50);
```

How can I `optimize` above code, without changing final result ?

Comment: in theory 3x3 would be the right filter size (5x5 is 2 pixel in each direction, 3x3 is 1 pixel in each direction) but I doubt that you will get exact same values. Maybe if you adjust the gaussian terms (solve some equations?). But remember to check the parameters of resize, since there might be some interpolation techniques included!!

Answer (score 2):

[pyrDown()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#pyrdown) might be doing both required steps in one go.

Comment: it would smooth the original large image but this is required to avoid aliasing.